# drop duplicates columns with a groupBy funtion

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, filter, window

Hello I have the following dataframe

```
NAME ID   VER
 A.  650.  true
 A.   230.  false
 B.   430.  false
 B.   230.  false
 C.   125.  true
 C.   230.  false
```

So here the target is to drop duplicate columns and to only keep one. Here I want to remove the second line because it has same Name as the first one but with a VER equal to false.

same for the last column whose name is C we only keep the one having a true Ver , for B ones , we keep both of them because there is no Ver equal to true.

The expected result would be

```
  NAME ID   VER
 A.  650.  true
 B.   430.  false
 B.   230.  false
 C.   125.  true
```

So here I though about  a window function partitioned by name and then filter over VER to only keep the Names having a true Ver

ANy idea how to implement this with spark SQL

Comment: why not just use the `join`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a flag column based on whether there are any True's for a given name:

```
spark.sql("""
    select NAME, ID, VER 
    from (
        select *, 
            max(VER) over(partition by NAME) == false or VER as flag 
        from df
    ) 
    where flag
""").show()
+----+----+-----+
|NAME|  ID|  VER|
+----+----+-----+
|  A.|650.| true|
|  C.|125.| true|
|  B.|430.|false|
|  B.|230.|false|
+----+----+-----+
```

Comment: will take the first true and if there are other Ver equal to true we will loose them

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to use the `join`.

```
spark.sql("""
    SELECT a.NAME, a.ID, a.VER
      FROM df a
      LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT DISTINCT NAME
             FROM df
            WHERE VER = true) b
        ON a.NAME = b.NAME
     WHERE (b.NAME IS NOT NULL AND a.VER = true)
        or (b.NAME IS NULL AND a.VER = false)
""")

+----+---+-----+
|NAME|ID |VER  |
+----+---+-----+
|A   |650|true |
|B   |430|false|
|B   |230|false|
|C   |125|true |
+----+---+-----+
```